# Dynamic variable from array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array, and it counts a probability of every possible combination of arrays' elements. But i need to store every probability in a variable.

```
    $array_for_19=[
["A 1","A 1","A 1", "A 2","A 3","A 2","A 1","A 3", "A 2", "A 1","A 3", "A 3", "A 2","A 1", "A 2"],
["A a","A a","A c", "A b","A c","A c","A c","A a", "A a", "A c","A c", "A a", "A a","A a", "A c"],
["1 a","1 b","1 a", "1 a","1 b","1 c","1 b","1 c", "1 b", "1 a","1 a", "1 c", "1 b","1 a", "1 a"],
["2 a","2 a","2 a", "2 a","2 a","2 a","2 a","2 b", "2 b", "2 a","2 a", "2 b", "2 a","2 b", "2 b"],
["3 b","3 c","3 b", "3 c","3 a","3 b","3 c","3 b", "3 b", "3 b","3 c", "3 c", "3 a","3 c", "3 b"]];
function algorithms19_20($array){
    for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
        $newarray=[];
        for($j=0;$j<count($array[$i]);$j++){
            $splitted=split(" ", $array[$i][$j]);
                array_count_values($array[$i]);
            array_push($newarray, $splitted);   

        }
        $keycount1;
        foreach (array_count_values($array[$i]) as $key => $value) {
                $keycount1++;
                $probabilty=round(($value/count($array[$i])),2);
                echo "$key - <strong>$value</strong> <br/>Probability: $probabilty<br/>"; 
                ${(string)$key}=$probabililty;
                echo $A1;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
```

But I understand, that my key for example is "A 1", so variable can not be called like $A 1. So how can I make this work?

Comment: `str_replace(' ', '', 'A 1')` should work nicely. Also, use count() outside the loop and pass it in as variable. For every iteration of the loop count() will be called again. It's a performance loss without any good reason.

Comment: Ok, will have in mind about `count`, but `str_replace` somewhy doesnt work

Comment: What functionality are you expecting from dynamically named variables that cannot be done with arrays? The general consensus is that dynamically named variables are needlessly complicated and usually don't add anything; what can be achieved by `$A1` that cannot be achieved by `$array['A1']`?

Comment: So how to achieve that i could get $A1 with value of probability? I wouldnt bother about it if i didnt need to multiply it later...